# SecurityError: The operation is insecure.when using AjaxUpload library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Valums AjaxUpload library for uploading images, and all of a sudden I'm getting **SecurityError: The operation is insecure.** errors. Nothing's changed apart from a bit of html, (I've added value attributes to text inputs and a src to an img tag).

I've seen a few answers [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275104/new-file-the-operation-is-insecure) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878406/how-to-prevent-operation-is-insecure-warning-when-dynamically-inserting-javasc) but I'm not sure these apply as this was working before, and now it isn't. I'm uploading files from the same directory I always have been.

Has anyone else had the issue with this warning randomly starting to appear? The domain the script is running on doesn't use SSL so I can see any reason this error would be a http/https thing, especially since none of the JS code has changed.

EDIT: The error seems to get thrown on this line

```
$('input[name=image]').val(response.data.url);
```

I'll do some digging see if I can figure out why

Here's the JS for my upload function

```
new AjaxUpload( $('#imageUpload'),{

     action: '/sivactivities/ajax/upload',
     name: 'image',
     data: {
           'itemId' : DataBridge.itemId
     },

     onSubmit : function(file, ext){
                 // If you want to allow uploading only 1 file at time,
         // you can disable upload button
         this.disable();


     },
     onComplete: function(file, response){

         // enable upload button
        this.enable();

        response = SIV.decode(response);
        console.log(response);
        DataBridge.imageHeight = response.data.height;
        DataBridge.imageWidth = response.data.width;
        DataBridge.thumbSrc = response.data.url;
        $('#image-upload-load').hide();
        $('input[name=image]').val(response.data.url);
        $('#uploadedImg').attr('src', response.data.url);
     }
});
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="formKey">Image</div>
<div class="formVal">
    <p>Please make sure this image is 246 x 164</p>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;float:left;">
        <div class="upload-button"><a class="smaller-button imageUpload" id="imageUpload" href="#"/><span></span>BROWSE</a></div>
        <div style="height: 75px;" id="divFileProgressContainer"></div>
        <div class="form-loading hide" id="item-upload-load">
            <img src="/open/img/loading-indicator.gif" alt="loading"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="image" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block; width:300px;">
        <img id="uploadedImg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some further debugging it turns out I was trying to update the value of the file input, rather than the image (both elements had ID **image**).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12250064/993600) made me check the ID's and ultimately solved my problem.